Integrating/Automating Fresh Sales CRM with Google Sheet
I am trying to integrate fresh sales CRM with google sheet. I have tried few automation tools like Zapier, Integrately etc; The problem is they only allow a set of records in their free plan. I have around 2000 rows to be created on google sheet. Also whenever these records are updated on fresh sales, it should only update the existing row and not duplicate the entry. I am not considering a paid plan as of now. is there a way to integrate with tools like BigQuery instead of Google Sheet. a small lead would be helpful for me to go ahead
I tried some automation tools which they only allow 100 rows per month. I also tried integrating it with skyvia - I am getting an error - Integration failed: Invalid data[37118]: Unable to parse range: SkyVia Integration!A0:A0 Error code: 400
Thanks
